# Things needed to deploy a web app in Heroku with custom domain

Tags: heroku, web-deployment, web-hosting

I am new to web development and I am about to deploy my web app via Heroku and want it to have a custom domain name. I am confused about certain considerations. For now my understanding is:

1. I would need to buy domain name from a domain registrar (e.g. Hostgator).
2. I also need to purchase a web hosting service (e.g. Hostgator).
3. If I want to 'scale' I would also need to subscribe to Heroku's paid services.

What I'm not sure about is, are the services of No.2 (Web hosting) and No.3 (Heroku) different? What exactly is it that I am paying for with each service. It seems to me that when using Heroku, my code is already 'hosted' there so what am I paying for with Hostgator? Also need tips on what 'tier'/pricing solution to choose on Heroku/Web hosting. How much traffic would I need to consider increasing the amount of process types in Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to purchase a domain name, you don't need a hosting service as well as Heroku. When you've got your domain name you will then point the records according to [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) document. Also, you might want to consider your DNS Provider more carefully based on [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains) reference.

It's very difficult to give tips to tiers as it very much is related to your application. slow code will always be slow code. You want to make sure your code is efficient as possible to maximise the resources of the dyno. When you achieve that you can scale up vertically (more CPU/RAM) and horizontally for more throughput.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this confusion started because when I was following your first link, Hostgator does not allow me to configure my CNAME record without buying a package (webhosting) from them. Just to be clear, I would only need a domain name and a DNS provider (is this different form a web host) to achieve what I want?

Comment: right, so consider buying a doman name from a provider that will let you just buy one of them without hosting. You don't need a hosting provider if you're going to be deploying to Heroku.